# How to fix - Failed to execute goal org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.4.0:check (default)

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

"Failed to execute goal org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.4.0:check (default) on project user-test-common: Found duplicate classes/resources!"

I am getting above error message when I am trying to build a maven project locally by changing one of its dependency's version and leaving other dependencies version point to same version, as described below,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.interfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>Interface-1</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.interfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>Interface-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc.interfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>Interface-3</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.NEW</version>
      </dependency>
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: The information provided is not sufficient for us to help. Is `com.abc.interfaces` private project? What is different between 1.1 and 1.1.NEW? 
What I can suggest now is run `mvn dependency:tree` to see any suspicious dependency causing duplication.